# Sharepoint 2013 Web Part List Filter Does Not Work

Tags: web-part, filter

I've added my SharePoint web part list filter and when the selection is made it adds the filtered icon on the column I've chosen; however, it doesn't filter to the unique value I've selected.

Funny thing is, when I click 'Clear Filters From' option it then applies the filter and presents me the result I wanted.

I've added the example below to show the three stages.

What am I doing wrong...?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the filter webpart works best on a page, not on the library itself, as it interacts/interferes with the views. Make a new page, add the list app, and add the filter app, and try it from there.

Comment: Hi Blake, I can no longer see your image included in your question, but wanted to see if you've had better luck? I can further explain my response if it's still an issue. I had encountered the same trouble myself before.